# Optimal webpack.config with webpack 2 for AngularJS 1.x app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I want to set up an Angular 1.x app from scratch using webpack 2.

I am having trouble finding the best configuration for `webpack.config`, with optimal `entry` and `output` for production (meaning, all code, style and templating minified and gziped with no code repetition).

My main problem is how to set up `webpack.config` so that it recognizes all partials within the folder structure of my project, like these:

[image]

My current config file, for reference (which can't see subfolders):

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
var ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );
var path = require( 'path' );

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        contentBase: path.join( __dirname, '/dist' ),
        open: true,
        port: 9000,
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, '/dist' ),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( {
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
                publicPath: '/dist'
            } )
        } ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            hash: true,
            minify: { collapseWhitespace: true },
            template: './src/index.html',
            title: 'Prov'
        } ),
        new ExtractTextPlugin( {
            filename: 'main.css',
            allChunks: true
        } )
    ]
};
```

Comment: so you have the `app.js` do you want to import your partials into app.js or compile `proverb-list.js` as a separate directive/controller?

Comment: If I am correct in understanding your question (i.e. compiling partials via webpack)
you have two options, 1. either push your partials (via glob or per-file) into the entry, or 2. import them into app.js and commonChuck. -

Comment: Yes I think you understood it correctly, does option 2 mean I should import all my js files to `app.js` using require, and all `html` templates to the directives themselves also using require?

Comment: you can do that yes - you'll need `html-loader` for the templates. If you wanted to split the directives into individual bundles (instead of `app.bundle.js`) you can either use the `CommonChunksPlugin` or append those files into your `entry`

Comment: I'm having trouble understaing which `webpack.config` setup would be the optimal route and which practices do I have to pay attention to during development to guarantee that the code will work in production (i.e. Should I require everything in `app.js` or in a separate `index.js` file? Should I require my templates and styles on a per-component basis or otherwise?)

Comment: Initially, you'd require everything into `app.js`, but that isn't optimal since you don't require every component on app load (browserify vs webpack) (how do you split files into smaller chunks when required?) - this is where `CommonChunksPlugin` is useful. 
Say you have `app-2.js` which is similar but different to `app.js`... you can add `app-2.bundle.js` manually to your entry file. It depends though. I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this isn't an exhaustive solution, as there are many optimizations one can make in the frontend, and I've kept the code snippets fairly short.

With webpack, there are a few routes that you can take to include partials into your `app.js`.

**Solution 1**
You can import/require your partials within `app.js` as such:

**app.js**

```
var angular = require('angular');
var proverbList = require('./proverb/list/proverb.list');
// require other components

// set up your app as normal
```

This allows the `app.bundle.js` to include your component `js` files in the main bundle. You can also use `html-loader` to include templates in the final bundle.

This isn't ideal, as all it does is create a large `bundle.js` (which doesn't leverage multiple downloads with `http2` nor does it allow loading of components/files when the user explicitly requires it).

**Solution 2**
Importing partials as separate entry files into your webpack bundle:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const globby = require('globby');
const sourceDir = 'src';
var webpackentry = {
    app: `${__dirname}/src/app.js`
};

const glob = globby.sync(`${__dirname}/${sourceDir}/**/*.js`)
    .map((file)=>{
    let name = file.split('/').pop().replace('.js', '');
    webpackentry[name] = file;
});


const config = {
  entry: webpackentry,
  ...
}
```

The second solution is unorthodox but it can be useful if you wanted to split all your partials as `<script>` tags in your html (for example if your company/team uses that as a means to include your directive/components/controllers), or if you have an `app-2.bundle.js`.

**Solution 3**
Use `CommonsChunkPlugin`:

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpackentry = {
  vendor: [
   'module1',
   'module2',
   'module3',
  ]
}
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['vendor'] //... add other modules
  })
]
```

[CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) allows webpack to scrawl through your entry files and discern common modules that are shared among them. This means that even if you are importing `module1` in different files, they will be compiled only once in your final bundle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is supposed to be in the `manifest` file, even after reading the official documentation, which states: "we need to extract out the runtime into a separate manifest file". What exactly goes in that file and how is it different from a regular `entry.js` or `app.js`?

Comment: quoting from survive.js `When webpack writes bundles, it maintains a manifest as well. The manifest describes what files webpack should load. It's possible to extract it and start loading the files of the project faster instead of having to wait for the vendor bundle to be loaded.`

Comment: btw - @Tiago does this work for you? - (please confirm the answer if it is satisfactory)

Comment: Still working it out, I will confirm it as soon as it does.

Comment: @Tiago any luck on this?